# Cannot set ping interval to small value

Tags: 14.04, networking, ping

I am using Ubuntu 14.0.4 LTS with Kernel 4.8.0-46-generic. I am trying to ping a peer device with ping interval lower than 1 second e.g 0.2 but I am not able to do that. I get the following error :

`ping: bad timing interval`

I execute ping in sudo mode but still without success. Have any one encountered this issue before?

Note: I tried on the other device which has Kernel 4.2.0 and it worked under sudo mode.

Comment: `sudo ping -c3 -i 0.15 www.google.com` works for me.

Comment: what do you get for `ping -V`? i.e. what version are you using?

Comment: @DougSmythies the version of the ping is `s20150815`. It is strange because the version on the other laptop which has Kernel 4.2.0 is `s20121221`

Comment: Well, that exact same version works for me.

Answer (score 3):

The manual to ping states that only the super-user may set an interval to less than 0.2 seconds.

```
   -i interval
          Wait  interval seconds between sending each packet.  The default
          is to wait for one second between each packet normally,  or  not
          to  wait in flood mode. Only super-user may set interval to val‐
          ues less than 0.2 seconds.
```

I tried this out on a clean 14.04 installation and sub 0.2 intervals only work for the super-user, this is to stop ping floods from unprivileged users.

Comment: I have already executed the ping with sudo and in sudo bash and I am still getting the same error. However it worked on the other  machine with Kernel 4.2.0

Answer (score 3):

In my case ping was using the current locale to interpret the interval value: `ping -i 0.3 <ip>` didn't work but `ping -i 0,3 <ip>` does.

This bug [Decimal separator in ping -i  is locale dependent](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1283277) from 2015 in Fedora's bugzilla says it is a bug(and I agree: scripts shouldn't change behavior depending on the system's locale)

This bug is affecting Ubuntu 20.04 (reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/iputils/+bug/1904251))

Answer (score 1):

Try with command

```
sudo ping XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX -A
```

This command send packet as fast as possible 
More option you have [here](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ping)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use uppercase **I**

```
sudo ping -I eth1 111.111.111.111
```